# Can't run Java 7 on Spring 2.5 App. Says it needs Java 1.5 or Later

Tags: java, spring, maven, visual-studio-code, tomcat8

I am currently using the VSCode ide to work with a Spring 2.5 application with Maven. Because of the old Spring version, I understand that the app will not recognize Java versions beyond 7. I also posted previously about the exact same problem, and was informed that my Tomcat version was incompatible with Java apps before 8.

To combat this, I downloaded and installed Tomcat 8.5, and installed Java 7, which should be able to work with eachother based on my research. However despite this change, I have run into the same error as before.

[Tomcat 8.5]: Jul 27, 2021 2:18:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet [SiteAdmin]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context namespace element 'annotation-config' and its parser class [org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigBeanDefinitionParser] are only available on JDK 1.5 and higher

I have tried changing the Java compile source and target in the pom.xml file, as well as changing the jdk to 1.7, but the problem persists.

I should mention I do also have Java 11 installed on my computer, due to it being a requirement to run the VSCode IDE. Also despite setting the system path variables to point otherwise, running Java -version results in version 11 being called. I do not know why this is the case, but it may be related to the problem.

Any help on this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Spring 2.5 was launched fully [compatible with Java 6](https://spring.io/blog/2007/11/19/spring-framework-2-5-released). Have you tried that version? (Do keep in mind that [Tomcat compatible with that version of Java are archived](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html))

Comment: You may have even more versions of java installed.

Comment: You're going to have to be extra careful and make sure the whole build chain is java 7.  My guess is that the compiler you're using is making bytecode that is 1.7  compatible, but still attempting to compile against the jre 11 rt.jar.  Try building using the maven command line, after setting JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME, and PATH environment variables to point to your JDK7 installation.   Then if you follow @darnold0714 advice for making sure tomcat is setup correctly, you've got a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Old Spring versions like 2.5 had a Java version check. This check was/is not able to detect newer Java versions (>= 8) correctly and then causes some strange exceptions as you mentioned.

So it is likely that your Tomcat is not using Java 7 but Java 11.

To check if this is the problem, the easiest way is to change the system's default Java installation to Java 7 (just for testing). Then start Tomcat and check if the problem has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Tomcat on Windows, you can set Tomcat & Java variables in $CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.bat.  You could explicitly point JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME at any Java install you may have.

When you run $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.bat, it will know to run setenv.bat first and set the environment up as you need it.

Source: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/RUNNING.txt

Comment: Tomcat on Windows usually does not use the `*.bat` scripts, but runs as a service. The path to the appropriate `jvm.dll` can be configured in Prunmgr (aka Tomcat Monitor).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I agree.  For something production quality, one would run it as a service.  When I ran Tomcat 8.5 on Windows, I used this guide: 

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/windows-service-howto.html